simplivre document class does not work (miktex)
I wanted to try out the simplivre document class for miktex. After installing a lot of additional packages, I can't get the provided examples to work. For example, the compilation of file "simplivre-demo-style-classical.tex" from the delivered demos leads to the following error message:
! Package create-theorem Error: The theorem-like environment "commentary"
(create-theorem)                cannot be created, you have to name it
(create-theorem)                before initialization.

The package "create-theorem" I even had to install manually, because miktex' automatic "on-the-fly" installation did recognize this depencency. But even then, it did not work. Unfortunately there is no documentation for this class. Has anyone had similar experiences?
Here the file "simplivre-demo-style-classical.tex" from the demo zip file that want to compile:
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,
   %use font = times, % garamond, newcm, lmodern, ...
  use osf,
  use style = classical,
  % use indent = false,
  % title in boldface,
  % title in scshape,
  % title in sffamily,
  % theorem in new line,
  emphasize theorems,
  theorem numbering = section,
  % number theorems separately,
  simple name,  % for clever referencing
  name in link, % for clever referencing
]{simplivre}
\usepackage{ProjLib}
\usepackage[
    % lang     = {french},
    type     = {CC},
    modifier = {by},
    version  = {4.0},
    hyperxmp = false,
]{doclicense}



\usepackage{blindtext}

%% \UseLanguage{French}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\SwitchTheoremNumbering{example,examples,claim}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\TitlePage [ style = simple, author info on the right ]
  {
    % , logo      = { }  % the logo image
    , title     = { \fontspec{SourceSansPro}[WordSpace={1.25,1,1}]
                    \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=2.0}
                    Title of the book\\(demo of the style \textquote{classical})
                  }
    , author    = { Author Name }
    , date      = { \today[only-year-month] }
    % , date      = { \TheDate{2024-01} }
    , info      = {
                    This text is... \blindtext
                  }
    , license   = { \addfontfeature{Numbers=Lining} \medskip\doclicenseThis }
    , license page name = { Info }
  }

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\mainmatter

\part{Basic examples}
\parttext{Some introductory text.}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\section{Section title}

\subsection{Subsection title}

Some introductory text.

\begin{definition}[something]
  Define something.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}[some result]\label{thm:result}\index{Theorem on some result}
  The statement.
\end{theorem}

\begin{emphasis}
  Clever reference: \cref{thm:result} (only name: \namecref{thm:result}, only number: \labelcref{thm:result}).
\end{emphasis}

An equation:\index{Euler's equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Euler}
  \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi} + 1 = 0.
\end{equation}

\begin{emphasis}
  Reference of equation: \eqref{eq:Euler} or \cref{eq:Euler}.
\end{emphasis}

\SetTheorem{corollary}{shared counter = subsubsection}
\begin{corollary}[of \cref{thm:result}]\label{cor:result}
  Some corollary.
\end{corollary}
\SetTheorem{corollary}{shared counter = subsection}
\begin{proof}
  Some lines of proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{examples}
  \begin{enumerate}
      \item First example.
      \item Second example.
      \item Third example.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{examples}

\begin{example*}[Important example]
  The numbering is switched in the preamble, thus \verb|example*| is the numbered version while \verb|example| is the unnumbered version.
\end{example*}

\begin{proof}[Proof of \cref{thm:result}]
    Some lines of proof.
\end{proof}

\part{Demonstration}

\blinddocument

\backmatter

\printindex

\end{document}



Can you show your .log file?

As always please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. As you're using miktex the standard question is also whether your miktex is properly up to date? If you have both user and admin mode, remember to update both.

The log file is too large. I do not know how to share it. The mentioned sample file that I want to compile is added to original post. Also want to mention that my miktex installation is properly updated, etc.

If it  is too large for the question, you could post it on pastebin.com or similar services

log file is here: https://pastebin.com/e4r0cATs

do you have the font SourceSansPro installed? you either need to install it or override that setting, I guess. this is included in texlive, so miktex can probably install it, too. or you can install it for your system, obviously.

The create-theorem might not be installed properly. Check if the file create-theorem-preset-names-cleveref.tex can be found by latex. As a test, you could place it in the same folder as your .tex file.

(if you would like to avoid all these problems with missing packages in the future, you could consider replacing miktex with texlive. Texlive allows to do a complete installation which will contain (almost) all packages)

file "create-theorem-preset-names-cleveref.tex" cannot be found by latex though i placed it in the same folder as the main tex file.

I also cannot install SourceSansPro font in Windows. Apparently this belongs to Adobe and cannot be downloaded. I think I contact the authors of simplivre via github bug tracker.

it is an adobe font, but it is released under the open font licence. linux distros package it. texlive packages. I'd assume miktex does.

the example you posted compiles fine for me with luatex. it is not a simplivre bug but an installation issue.

OK, after installing SourceSansPro, it compiles but the problems with create-theorem persist.

it compiles without errors here.

OK that means ultimately that my installation is faulty. Thanks for your support and consider to close this thread.

the create-theorem version in miktex is from 2023/07/23, in texlive I have 2024/02/25. I guess that is the source of the problem. Report that to miktex, they should update the package.

Great. I will do. Thank you.
